# Designing an API to accept interface references it produced

Tags: c#, api, interface, abstraction

### Overview

I'm working on an application which uses two main levels of abstraction:

- The core library defines a number of interfaces, and contains classes which implement core functionality in terms of the interfaces. In this way, I hope to write the core algorithms once, but make them applicable to any number of interface implementations.
- An "implementation" library provides *one particular* implementation of the set of interfaces, using a third-party SDK. Ultimately there will be more than one of these libraries; which one is used will be determined by configuration.

The application itself instantiates classes from the SDK library and uses them to satisfy the core library's dependencies.

### Problem

The problem I need to solve looks like this in general:

```
// Algorithm in the core (interfaces are all implemented by the SDK library):
ICorrespondentRepository allCorrespondents = ...;
ICorrespondent correspondent = allCorrespondents.FindByName(...);
...
IDocumentRepository allDocuments = ...;
IDocument document = allDocuments.FindByTitle(...);

// Problem: Implementation needs state not exposed
// on ICorrespondent in order to do this:
document.SetRecipient(correspondent);
```

In other words: an `IDocument` can have its recipient set to a previously obtained `ICorrespondent`. When `SetRecipient` is called, the implementation of `IDocument` needs state (a primary key unimportant to the core) associated with - but not exposed by - `ICorrespondent`, in order to actually effect the change.

One way to do it is by downcasting `ICorrespondent` to the actual implementation class inside `SetRecipient`, but this feels extremely clunky. Even worse is keeping a map from interface references to internal state.

The root of the problem seems to be that the interfaces are designed exclusively to serve the generic needs of the core library, even though they effectively have two consumers with different requirements: the core, and the implementation library which produced them.

Are there better ways to redesign this kind of requirement?

Comment: Can you not wrap up that state in some type of other interface that is exposed by `ICorrespondent`? I think you'll still have to downcast somewhere, but that's the price of parallel abstractions.

Comment: @siride Thanks for the suggestion. I considered that, but given that the state is specific to the implementation, it seems pretty much equivalent to downcasting to the class.

Comment: it would still separate out the concern of external persistent references into its own interface.

Comment: @siride Having implemented it the way you suggest, I can see the benefit of doing so. Encapsulating the state in an (internal) interface helps to delineate the responsibilities of e.g. the `SetRecipient` method, whereas downcasting to the implementing class instead would give the method access to lots of things it doesn't need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, what you want to do is cross-casting.

You say that the specific implementation of `IDocument` is not compatible with all subclasses of `ICorrespondent`, therefore your call to `SetRecipient` may legitimately fail if the instance of `ICorrespondent` that is passed does not have this primary key. Having this primary key is a "trait" of compatible subclasses.

The technique you may use is this one. Define an interface.

```
internal interface IHasPrimaryKey {
    PrimaryKey GetPrimaryKey();
}
```

And your compatible `ICorrespondent` class should implement both interfaces.

```
internal class CompatibleCorrespondent : ICorrespondent, IHasPrimaryKey {
    // ...
}
```

And the `SetRecipient` in this case should try a cross-cast of the correspondent to see if it provides the necessary primary key, and fail otherwise.

```
var hasPrimaryKey = correspondent as IHasPrimaryKey;
if(hasPrimaryKey == null) {
    throw new InappropriateSubclassException();
}
// ...
var pk = hasPrimaryKey.GetPrimaryKey();
```

This is the most strongly-typed solution that you can get out of this kind of architecture. The failure case is legitimate, since the typesystem does not guarantee that you'll get your primary key in every case.

This has the advantage that you're not bound to a specific subclass. Any class implementing both `ICorrespondent` and `IHasPrimaryKey` is suitable.

Of course, I'll let you find more appropriate names for your specific code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is pretty much what I ended up going with. It's the same suggestion that siride made in the comments, but casting it in terms of the specialised library checking for "traits" it can identify, and the core interfaces documented to fail when passed incompatible instances, makes it a pretty solid solution in my mind.

Comment: Indeed. Had I implemented this when was younger, I would have done it with Reflection, checking for a property with a specific name, but cross-casting is much much cleaner. You get the most out of the static type system this way.